# Information regarding the Run time error 9

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy the range of value from one sheet in excel to another. I have copied this formula from another part of my sheet that works however i cam coming up with the run time error 9.

```
Sub SaveJambStudEC()
'
' SaveCalcsJambEC Macro
'
Dim page As Integer
    page = Cells(4, "T").Value

    Range("A70:AN70").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("A71").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(page, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("A1:O63").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("10.3 JambCalcs EC").Select
        Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset((page - 1) * 63, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Sheets("9.3 Jamb Design EC").Select

    Range("T5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("T31").Value = 0

    Call JambECsetDesignOptions
    Call CopyJambOptiValues

    Range("J9").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Tell us which line errors and (2) read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: The Error is happening on: Sheets("10.3 JambCalcs EC").Select

Comment: The error means that the active workbook does not contain a sheet named "10.3 JambCalcs EC".  If in fact it does contain a sheet with that name, check for spelling errors and extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

using the below code you will check if there is a sheet with that name. if you dont receive any message box means that there is no sheet with such name

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name = "10.3 JambCalcs EC" Then
            MsgBox "Sheet Appears"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Note**

'ThisWorkbook' refer to the workbook that the code included. If you want to clearly declare the workbook you could declare a variable 'Dim wb as Workbook' and then set the workbook 'Set wb=Workbooks("workbook name")'

Comment: Caveat: OP's code looks like it originated as a recorded macro, so that would be written in a standard procedural module, which means the `Cells` and `Range` and `ActiveCell` calls are all off whatever workbook is currently active, i.e. `ActiveWorkbook` - which may or may not be `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon thanks for the clarification. I make a note in my answer trying to explain how to set a workbook variable.